# How can I debug OOM crashes in Deno

Tags: deno

I have a small Deno app that loads a number of objects from Redis, buts them in a Map<> and then processes the list on intervals.

There are ~70k items in the map.

After the app as been running a while, I get:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[15305:0x28fb00000000]   115966 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1399.1 (1402.3) -> 1398.9 (1403.8) MB, 1911.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.050, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[15305:0x28fb00000000]   117600 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 1399.4 (1402.3) -> 1399.2 (1403.0) MB, 1632.3 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.025, current mu = 0.001) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal javascript OOM in Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit
#
```

I tested increasing the old space size with: `--v8-flags=--max-old-space-size=8192`

Which makes the app run a bit longer, then crash with:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[15462:0x3c300000000]   303937 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 3930.6 (3936.0) -> 3930.5 (3939.7) MB, 20.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.911, current mu = 0.725) allocation failure 
[15462:0x3c300000000]   303960 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 3931.9 (3937.2) -> 3931.4 (3939.7) MB, 19.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.911, current mu = 0.725) allocation failure 
[15462:0x3c300000000]   303993 ms: Scavenge (reduce) 3931.9 (3937.2) -> 3931.8 (3944.7) MB, 31.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.911, current mu = 0.725) allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->


#
# Fatal javascript OOM in MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed
#
```

I suspect I have a memory leak in my code, but how can I

- Get a heap dump on OOM and inspect it?
- Continuously monitor memory (and other) metrics of Deno

Answer (score 1):

One way to get heap dumps is to connect to the process with Chrome or VSCode.

It can be done by adding  `--inspect-brk` command line option when running Deno.

https://deno.land/manual@v1.0.0/tools/debugger

As of 2020-09 they state:

> profiling and memory dumps might not work correctly